# How do we restrict a user to see a field in a post without registration,

Tags: content-restriction

How do we restrict a user to see a field in a post without registration, after registration the user will be able to see the link.

I have a project in which I have created a post from an excelsheet by a plugin, now I want to hide a field of link with login/register button, after registration the user will able to see this link.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean on the front end;

```
<?php
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        // Only visible when logged in
    } else {
        // Only visible when not logged in
    }
?>
```